# How to enable usb debugging on android with black screen?

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I was trying to enable **USB debugging** option on my Samsung Galaxy J1 Ace (SM-J110H) handset. As you already know that the screen is black/dead but except that the cellphone is working just fine. Somehow I managed to enable the USB debugging option by using an OTG cable and a USB keyboard(and off-course a lot of screenshots). But still unable to authorize USB debugging for my pc as I'm not able to click `always allow from this computer`.

So how do I allow/ authorize USB debugging from my pc? TIA

Comment: This is simple. When you debug for the first time then give the permission of **allow this computer for all time**. If you are not able to do this then use WI-FI adb tool https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/7339992

Answer (score 1):

Ι would write it here as a comment, because answer is not based on facts, however on black screens I try to remember the basic buttons and can use some of my phones even blindfolded.

However when I was having a similar problem, I used a tool called ADB that made it possible to access some of my Lenovo A390's shell features via Windows CMD and managed to turn on USB-Debugging and even download some backup files from a password-holder app I used in that time.

https://www.androidphonesoft.com/resources/enable-usb-debugging-android-broken-screen.html

There was also a stack exchange topic that helped me run through the process.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112040/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-if-forgotten-pattern-for-screen-unlock

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -2):

Have two phones. The one with the dead screen and a working one. Download any app that can mirror an Android to another. Use the mouse to download it. Install it in the two phones. You can download apps like airdoid. Create account on the good phone, then login into the same account on both phones. U will be able to control the other phone with the working phone so that you accept the debugging prompt when it appears

Comment: How can using a mouse help if the phone screen is black?